# Who owns the logo of a company after the company declares bankruptcy?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, ownership, bankruptcy

Who owns the logo of a company after the company declares bankruptcy? For example who owns the logo for toys R'us after they declare bankrupt?

Answer (score 5):

Whoever buys it.

When a company declares bankruptcy then its assets are owned by its creditors, as compensation for the standing debts.

Since usually there are multiple creditors, what happens is that its assets are sold/auctioned, as money is easier to divide between the different creditors<sup>1</sup>.

A logo or a trademark is an asset like any other and can be sold separately.

If nobody did come forward for the logo, then one of the creditors could accept it as part of its repayment.

---

<sup>1</sup> If a company is in bankruptcy it means that its assets cannot cover all of its debts, so creditors are usually paid only a part of their debts.

Comment: The usual way of looking at it is that the assets are held by the receiver/liquidator on trust for the creditors.  He can sell the logo to a creditor in exchange for writing off some debt, or to anybody else for cash which will be used to pay debts; but a creditor can't decide "I'll take the logo at this value against my debt".